# Javascript jQuery textbox creation and output

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Currently, I have a two table rows with two textboxes. I want to buid a button which allows the user to add and subtract an author row depending on how many they want. Once they increase the amount of authors they need for input, the user clicks on the generate button, the input from the textboxes will be outputed at the bottom of the page. I was trying to pull this off with javascript and jQuery. I am a ten day old student with javascript and jQuery and feel as if I have bit off more than I can chew.

An example of what I want can be found at this lnk: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/. However, I need the input from the textboxes outputed on the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Author</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="1" class="normalinput"            placeholder="Last"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="2" class="normalinput" placeholder="First"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Second Author (If Any)</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="3" class="normalinput"      placeholder="Last"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="4" class="normalinput" placeholder="First"></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<output id="20"></output>
<br>
<br>
 </body>
 </html>

<script type=text/javascript>
function myFunction()
{
var firstlast=document.getElementById("1").value;
if (firstlast==null || firstlast=="")
  {
  firstlast;
  }
else if(firstlast!=null || firstlast!="")
  {
  firstlast=document.getElementById("1").value + ", ";
  }

var firstfirst=document.getElementById("2").value;
if (firstfirst==null || firstfirst=="")
  {
  firstfirst;
  }
else if(firstfirst!=null || firstfirst!="")
  {
  firstfirst=document.getElementById("2").value + ". "; 
  }

var secondlast=document.getElementById("3").value;
if (secondlast==null || secondlast=="")
  {
  secondlast;
  }
else if(secondlast!=null || secondlast!="")
  {
  secondlast=document.getElementById("3").value + ", ";
  }

document.getElementById("20").innerHTML = firstlast + firstfirst + secondlast; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: In the current code you have you are not using jQuery at all. Are you asking how to use it for this?

Comment: Hi Brian, Yes I'm not using jQuery at all. I've been trying to for the past few days. Pieces of the code are working but I've struggled piecing it all together. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery

```
//wait for the document to be ready
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // when generate authors is clicked
    $("#generate-authors").click(function()
    {
        // get the first author row in your table
        var author = $(".author-row:first");

        // for the amount of authors put into the text box
        // insert a copy of the row after the last row
        for(i = 0; i < parseInt($("#author-amount").val()); i++)
            $(".author-row:last").after(author.clone());
    });

    // when output data is clicked
    $("#output-data").click(function()
    {
        // go through all the author rows
        $(".author-row").filter(function()
        {
            // add them to the output element
            $("#output").append("<p>" + $(this).find("[placeholder=\"Last\"]").val() + ", " + $(this).find("[placeholder=\"First\"]").val() + ".</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

The html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // put the script here
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="author-amount" type="text" />
        <input id="generate-authors" type="button" value="Generate" />
        <br />
        <input id="output-data" type="button" value="Output Data" />
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="author-row">
                    <td>Author</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="1" class="normalinput" placeholder="Last"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="2" class="normalinput" placeholder="First"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        <output id="output"></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the help with this. What I need is the Author textboxes ammended. Once the user is finished appending the textboxes, he  inputs the authors information and then clicks generate. When he clicks generate, the information is outputed on the html page.

Answer (score -1):

See this Example might be this is that what you want

HTML

```
<table id="table">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="1" class="normalinput"               placeholder="Last"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="2" class="normalinput" placeholder="First"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second Author (If Any)</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="3" class="normalinput"      placeholder="Last"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="4" class="normalinput" placeholder="First"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="generat" value="add">
<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove">    
<input type="button" id="display" value="display">        
<output id="20"></output>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#generat").click(function(){
        var clone = $("#table tr:first").clone();
        $("#table tbody:last").append(clone);

    });  
    $("#remove").click(function(){
        $("#table tbody tr:last").remove();

    });  
    $("#display").click(function(){
      $("#20").html("");
      $("table tr").each(function(){
         $(this).find("input").each(function(){
             $("#20").append(($(this).val()));
         });
      });
    }) 

});
```

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5BU8/3/)